# Code does not render properly when using const

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm following the Angular2 tutorial: [Tour of Heroes](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt2.html#!#displaying-our-heroes) So far everything has worked as expected. But at the point of the above link I cannot go through.

The code on the left is how they suggest I do it, but for some reason the application does not render correctly. But if I make a modification as you can see on the code on the right the application renders correctly. But I need to do it in the same way as hey suggest on the tutorial.

[image]

Probably the problem is with the `const` variable, I don't know.

Any idea on how to solve this?

Comment: You have misread the example; `const` is not an access modifier, so isn't valid inside the class definition. See the finished version of `app.component.ts` at the bottom of the page for the correct arrangement.

Comment: but as I've done so far on this tutorial I've been copying the code they suggest. This is the first time this fails. On their code suggestion they use: `const`.

Comment: Please **look at the complete example**, just above https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt2.html#!#the-road-we-ve-travelled. `const` is valid *outside* the class. With it inside the class you should somewhere see an error like `A class member cannot have the 'const' keyword.`

Comment: where can I see such error: `A class member cannot have the 'const' keyword.`?, is there a debugger that let me see it?

Comment: It depends what you're using to build and view the site. In your browser console? In the dev server output?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Windows Console. I took out that const definition out of the class but still not working

Comment: Beyond that give a [mcve]. And provide text next time, not screenshots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Class members cannot be defined with const. Within a class method you can define a const.

You may use private readonly typescript accessors for class members.

Comment: how do I use: private readonly typescript accessors for class members?

Comment: You prefix your member property with private readonly. If you don't know where private, readonly or const should be used - -  probably means you don't need them.

Comment: then I'm gonna remove the `const` and proceed with the tutorial. Thanks!